# Can you get the approximate battery percentage of the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, apple-watch

Does the Apple Watch have an object or function that can access its approximate battery life?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible but just from the release of WatchOS 4. The UIDevice is just for iOS devices so its absolutely not relevant for this question. The counterpart of it is the WKInterfaceDevice in WatchOS.

The correct solution is:

> OBJECTIVE-C version

```
float *watchBatteryPercentage = [WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;
```

but you have to allow it before with:

```
[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
```

> SWIFT 4.2 version:

```
var watchBatteryPercentage:Int {
    return Int(roundf(WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryLevel * 100))
}
```

and to make it available, you have to use:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift (WatchKit 4.x) version. Note you MUST set `isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true` or you won't get valid results. In my case, I don't care about the subsequent notifications, so I just set back to false immediately. Also note the current simulator does not emulate batteryLevel/batteryState.

```
    let curDevice = WKInterfaceDevice.current()
    curDevice.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true // Enable just long enough for data
    let chargeLevel = curDevice.batteryLevel
    let chargeState = curDevice.batteryState
    curDevice.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Sean, you can't get Apple Watch battery level in the current WatchKit version, and the following code simply returns iPhone battery level:

Swift:

```
var x = UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel
```

Objective-C:

```
int x = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;
```

This is the code used in the Battery Adviser Apple Watch app (by Applestan) on the App Store.

Answer (score -3):

This should work: `UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel`this will return a Float

Comment: This method returns the iPhone/iPad devices battery level and not the iWatch's battery level. In the current WatchKit version, there is no way to get the battery level of the watch.

Comment: I tested it on the simulator and I get a -1 for both the watch and the iPhone, but I can't tell for sure that it won't work on an actual Apple Watch. I still think it's a possible solution until they add the battery level in the WKInterfaceDevice.

Comment: I guess I can test my app on a real iPhone and then see if the real iPhone's battery matches or differs from the apple watch simulator's battery.